# How to select Entity A and your subclass Entity B with relationship OneToMany, using CriteriaBuilder construct?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, criteria

Using CriteriaBuilder how to select Entity A and names from Entity B, with CriteriaBuilder construct?

Entity A

```
public class EntityA {

   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<EntityB> entitiesB;


  //get and set 

}
```

Entity B

```
public class EntityB {

   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private EntityA entityA;


  //get and set 

}
```

Comment: Please check similar questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=jpa+criteriabuilder+onetomany+site:stackoverflow.com